# Using Itô's formula on product, problems with covariation process, Karatzas & Shreve, Proposition 3.5.4.

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

In the book "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" by Karatzas & Shreve we have a proposition on page 194, that I am having trouble with:

> Proposition 3.5.4.
>
> Fix $0 \leq T < \infty$ and assume that $Z(X)$ is a martingale. If $M \in \mathcal{M}_T^{c, \: loc}$, then the process
>   \begin{equation}
>   \widetilde M_t 
>   := 
>   \left\{ 
>   M_t - \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t X_s^{(i)} \: d \langle{M, W^{(i)}}\rangle_s, \mathcal{F}_t
>   \right\},
>   \qquad 0 \leq t \leq T
>  \end{equation}
>    is in $\widetilde{\mathcal{M}}_T^{c, \: loc}$. If $N \in {\mathcal{M}}_T^{c, \: loc}$ and 
>     \begin{equation*}
>   \widetilde N_t 
>   := 
>   N_t - \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t X_s^{(i)} \: d \langle{N, W^{(i)}}\rangle_s, 
>   \qquad 0 \leq t \leq T,
>  \end{equation*}
>    then
>    \begin{equation*}
>   \langle{\widetilde M, \widetilde N}\rangle_t = \langle{M, N}\rangle_t,
>   \qquad 0 \leq t \leq T,
>   \qquad \text{$P$- and $\widetilde P_T$-a.s.}
>  \end{equation*}
>    where the cross-variations are computed under the appropriate measures.

In the above
\begin{equation*}
  Z_t(X) 
  = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t Z_s(X)X_s^{(i)} \: d W_s^{(i)},
 \end{equation*}
where
$X = \{ X_t = ( X_t^{(1)}, \dots, X_t^{(d)} ), \mathcal{F}_t \}_{0 \leq t < \infty}$ is a vector of measurable, adapted processes satisfying
\begin{equation*}
 P \left[ 
 \int_0^T (X_t^{(i)})^2 \: d t < \infty 
 \right]
 = 1,
 \qquad 1 \leq i \leq d,
 \qquad 0 \leq T < \infty
\end{equation*}
and $W = \{ W_t = ( W_t^{(1)}, \dots, W_t^{(d)} ), \mathcal{F}_t \}_{0 \leq t < \infty}$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$.

I believe this is all the required information for my problem.

In the proof of the proposition, there are three calculations I am having trouble with:

> \begin{equation}
>   Z_t(X) \widetilde M_t
>   =
>   \int_0^t Z_u(X) \: d M_u
>   + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t \widetilde M_u X_u^{(i)} Z_u(X) \: d W_u^{(i)}.
>  \end{equation}

Here are my calculations for the first statement:

\begin{align}
  Z_t(X) \widetilde M_t
  =
  Z_0(X) \widetilde M_0
  + \int_0^t Z_u(X) \: d \widetilde M_u
  + \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d Z_u(X)
  + \langle  Z(X),  \widetilde M \rangle_t
  \\
  =
  \int_0^t Z_u(X) \: d \widetilde M_u
  + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t \widetilde M_u X_u^{(i)} Z_u(X) \: d W_u^{(i)}
  +  \langle  Z(X),  \widetilde M \rangle_t,
 \end{align}

since $Z_0(X) = 1$ and $\widetilde M_0 = 0$. As you can see the first integral is with respect to $\widetilde M$ and not $M$ and we also have a covariation process I am not sure what to do with. I am sure they are connected in some way, but cannot figure it out.

> \begin{equation*}
>  \begin{split}
>   \widetilde M_t \widetilde N_t - \langle{M,N}\rangle_t
>   &=
>   \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d N_u 
>   + \int_0^t \widetilde N_u \: d M_u
>   \\
>   &- \sum_{i=1}^d
>   \left(
>   \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d \langle{N, W^{(i)}}\rangle_u
>   + \int_0^t \widetilde N_u \: d \langle{M, W^{(i)}}\rangle_u
>   \right)
>  \end{split}
>  \end{equation*}

Here are my calculations for the second statement:
\begin{align}
 \widetilde M_t \widetilde N_t
 &=
 \widetilde M_0 \widetilde N_0
 + \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d \widetilde N_u 
 + \int_0^t \widetilde N_u \: d \widetilde M_u 
 + \langle \widetilde M, \widetilde N \rangle_t 
  \\
  %
  &=
   \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d N_u 
  + \int_0^t \widetilde N_u \: d M_u
  \\
  &- \sum_{i=1}^d
  \left(
  \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \: d \langle{N, W^{(i)}}\rangle_u
  + \int_0^t \widetilde N_u \: d \langle{M, W^{(i)}}\rangle_u
  \right)
  + \langle \widetilde M, \widetilde N \rangle_t,
  \end{align}

as you can see, I am very close to the desired statement, but I get $\langle \widetilde M_t, \widetilde N_t \rangle$ instead of $\langle M_t, N_t \rangle$, which is very strange. The statement of the proposition is to show these are almost surely equal to each other.

> \begin{equation*}
>  \begin{split}
>   &Z_t(X) 
>   \left( 
>   \widetilde M_t \widetilde N_t - \langle{M,N}\rangle_t
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &=
>   \int_0^t Z_u(X) \widetilde M_u \: d N_u
>   + \int_0^t Z_u(X) \widetilde N_u \: d M_u
>   \\
>   &+ \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t
>   \left( \widetilde M_u \widetilde N_u - \langle{M,N}\rangle_u \right)
>   X_u^{(i)} Z_u(X) \: d W_u^{(i)}.
>  \end{split}
>  \end{equation*}

Here are my calculations for the second statement:

\begin{align}
  Z_t&(X) 
  \left( 
  \widetilde M_t \widetilde N_t - \langle {M,N} \rangle_t
  \right) \\
  %
  &=
  Z_t(X) \widetilde M_t \widetilde N_t - Z_t(X) \langle {M,N}\rangle_t \\
  %
  &=
  Z_0(X) \widetilde M_0 \widetilde N_0
  + \int_0^t Z_u(X) \: d (\widetilde M_u \widetilde N_u)
  + \int_0^t \widetilde M_u \widetilde N_u \: d Z_u(X)
  + \langle Z(X), \widetilde M \widetilde N \rangle_t
  \\
  &- 
  \left(
  Z_0(X) \langle M,N\rangle_0
  + \int_0^t Z_u(X) \: d \langle {M,N} \rangle_u
  +
  \int_0^t \langle {M,N}\rangle_u \: d Z_u(X)
  +  \langle Z(X), \langle {M,N}\rangle \rangle_t
  \right),
 \end{align}

since $Z_0(X) = 1$ and $\widetilde M_0 = \widetilde N_0 = \langle M,N \rangle_0=0$, the product of these terms disappear. Any help on how to proceed with these calculations would be greatly appreciated. I am sure things get easier here at the end, if the previous calculations are accounted for, I seem to missing a fundamental clue, which is used in all calculations.